# How to use python to check whether there are unstaged/uncommitted change or unpushed commit in a git repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitpython

How to use python to check whether there are unstaged/uncommitted change or unpushed commit in a git repo?

I only know the command line

`git status` would tell

- unstaged change
- uncommitted stage
- also whether  current branch commit behind the remote or not

If I provide a root path such as ("C:/ProgramFiles") to the function,
It will be better if the code could give a list, where each element is the

`(path of this repos found under the root path, Unstaged/uncommited changes,  Untracked files:  , Latest commit is pushed)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html) package to help.

`pip install GitPython`

Then this script can give you a starting point:

```py
from git import Repo

repo = Repo('.')

print(f"Unstaged/uncommited changes: {repo.is_dirty()}")
print(f"Untracked files: {len(repo.untracked_files)}")

remote = repo.remote('origin')
remote.fetch()
latest_remote_commit = remote.refs[repo.active_branch.name].commit
latest_local_commit = repo.head.commit

print(f"Latest commit is pushed: {latest_local_commit == latest_remote_commit}")
```

Comment: people like you push StackOverflow forward so much!  It works

Comment: Could you kindly edit the ans in a way that gitpython could return all the paths and names of git repo under a given path?

Comment: What does "return all the paths and names of git repo under a given path" mean sorry? A list of all the tracked files?

Answer (score 1):

With `os.system()` function you can send shell command via python:

```
import os

os.system('git status')
```

If you want to manage the output you can use `os.popen()`:

```
import os

stream = os.popen('git status')
output = stream.read()
```

and find the shell printings into `output`.